# Pygame sprites escaping border

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a survival-based rpg game, but when I move the player sprite it would move out of the wall. I implemented a basic function to prevent this from happening, and it works.

```
if player.rect.x<0:
    player.rect.x=0
if player.rect.x>total_level_width:
    player.rect.x=total_level_width
if player.rect.y<0:
    player.rect.y=0
if player.rect.y>total_level_height:
    player.rect.y=total_level_height
```

It prevents the player sprite from moving out of the walls, but the sprite can still pass through the bottom and right walls.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you!

Full code:

```
import pygame
import random

black=(0,0,0)
white=(255,255,255)
green=(0,128,0)
skin=(255,224,189)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.image=pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(skin)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y
        self.change_x=0
        self.change_y=0
        self.speed=7

    def changespeed(self,x,y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

class Tree(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Tree,self).__init__()
        self.image=pygame.Surface([40, 40])
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image,green,(x,y),30,10)
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y
        self.wood=20

    def update(self):
        pass

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self,camera_func,width,height):
        self.camera_func=camera_func
        self.state=pygame.Rect(0,0,width,height)

    def apply(self,target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self,target):
        self.state=self.camera_func(self.state,target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l,t,_, _=target_rect
    _,_, w, h=camera
    l,t,_,_=-l+screen_width/2, -t+screen_height/2, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           
    l = max(-(camera.width-screen_width), l)
    t = max(-(camera.height-screen_height), t)
    t = min(0, t)                           

    return pygame.Rect(l, t, w, h)

pygame.init()

screen_width=800
screen_height=600
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption('Survive')

total_level_width=screen_width*5
total_level_height=screen_height*5
camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)

#sprites1 includes the player
#sprites2 includes trees

player=Player(20,20)
sprites1=pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites1.add(player)

sprites2=pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(2000):
    tree=Tree(random.randint(100,7900),random.randint(100,5900))
    sprites2.add(tree)

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
done=False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            done=True

        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_a:
                player.changespeed(-(player.speed), 0)
            elif event.key==pygame.K_d:
                player.changespeed(player.speed, 0)
            elif event.key==pygame.K_w:
                player.changespeed(0, -(player.speed))
            elif event.key==pygame.K_s:
                player.changespeed(0, player.speed)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.changespeed(player.speed, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.changespeed(-(player.speed), 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.changespeed(0, player.speed)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.changespeed(0, -(player.speed))

    camera.update(player)
    sprites1.update()
    sprites2.update()

    if player.rect.x<0:
        player.rect.x=0
    if player.rect.x>total_level_width:
        player.rect.x=total_level_width
    if player.rect.y<0:
        player.rect.y=0
    if player.rect.y>total_level_height:
        player.rect.y=total_level_height

    screen.fill(white)
    for e in sprites1:
        screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e)) 
    for e in sprites2:
        screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e)) 

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: use `player.rect.right` and `player.rect.bottom`. `Rect()` has not only `x`, `y` but many other useful values - `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, `center`, `centerx`, `centery`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) has other useful fields

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

So you can use `right` and `bottom`

```
if player.rect.right  > total_level_width:
    player.rect.right = total_level_width

if player.rect.bottom > total_level_height:
    player.rect.bottom = total_level_height
```

Answer (score 1):

A even easier method of implementing a game area is to define a rect, and in the update function of that sprite, use `pygame.Rect.clamp_ip(Rect_name)`
Heres an example

```
playarea = pygame.Rect(100, 100)
# inside of the player class...
def update():
    pygame.Rect.clamp_ip(playarea)
```